# Pandas DataFrame header to html

Tags: python, html, pandas

Unable to convert pandas header alone to html.
I have below code,

```
df = pd.read_csv("Employees.csv")
df1= df.columns.to_frame()
df1.to_html("upload.html")
```

Result of the code is ,

[image]

Expected result is,

[image]

Unable to get the header alone from the index of the data frame. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `headers` to false to get rid of the top row. And `index` to false to get rid of the first column.

```py
df1.to_html("upload.html", header=False, index=False)
```

You're left with the right column, which you can add styles to make it bold and centred like the left column.

[Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html)

Hope this helps!

Comment: The solution works though, the attributes are considered as table detail rather than table header.

Answer (score 0):

Customised the code to generate html attributes. This is more efficient as we can also add CSS and other html properties.

```
file = open("templates/upload.html", "w")
table = ["""<table border="1"> \n"""]
file.writelines(table)
file.close()

file = open("templates/upload.html", "a")
for row in list(df.columns):
    header = """<tr style="text-align: left;">\n<th>""" + row + "</th>\n</tr>\n"
    file.writelines(header)
file.close()

file = open("templates/upload.html", "a")
table = ["</table>"]
file.writelines(table)
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `df.head(0).to_html(header=True, index=False)` to get just the headers.